# Download PDF with python from a XHR request

Tags: python, pdf, download, python-requests, xmlhttprequest

I need to download a PDF that is hosted on this site: http://www.ioerj.com.br/portal/modules/conteudoonline/mostra_edicao.php?session=VG10V1JWSnFhelJPUkZGMFRqQldSVkpwTURCT2VsVTBURlJuTTA1VVNYUlBWVmt5VGxWT1FrMTZVa2ROVkZreVRWUlZOVTVxVVRKT2Ftc3pUbEU5UFE9PQ==
The PDF is requested via XHR with a JS module as you can [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Dtm.jpg)

I'm trying to get that XHR request to I can get the link for downloading the PDF

Comment: Hi @errepe! Welcome to SO! Please help us help you by posting what you have tried so far.

Comment: @MZ Hi! I actually have literally no idea how to solve this. I'm trying to build a program that allows me to download easily the PDF file without having to go over all this fuzz of inspecting the page.